# How to programmatically read and convert email in an image to text?

Tags: csv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have a CSV file with 1900+ entries of GIF image links.

Each image contains an email address.

I would like to programmatically read every entry and convert them in to its corresponding text, preferably in another or the same CSV file. I use Mac OS and prefer using Python or Java to accomplish this.

Any idea on how to do it using OCR or through any other methods? An example code will be greatly appreciated.

I've tried tesseract for a sample entry but the result wasn't accurate. Here's what I tried:

```
 $ tesseract email.gif out
```

*email.gif* looks like:

```
greentours2010@yahoo.com
```

The output generated in *out.txt* is:

```
gveen|L7uvs2ﬂ1ﬂ@yahLm cum
```

The CSV file looks as shown below (first 2 entries):

> - http://d1hnc0v5nyu4l2.cloudfront.net/kh/communications/original/1417577580/C2AFA720-7A9C-11E4-9201-22000AA51306?1417577580
> - http://d306v9rz034cgu.cloudfront.net/kh/communications/original/1367212416/55BE4627-B463-4523-8332-4046835D3D79?1367212416

This is my first question in SO. Apologies if I missed out any other relevant information. I will be happy to provide more.

Comment: What did you try so far, what are you result until now? Do all images have the same font and font size? How is the CSV format of interest for your problem? Do you want to use python? It is a bit much to ask people to give you example code for an email scrapper without providing anything. I am not the -1.

Comment: Urls not found 404 error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Your images are rather small and *blocky* for tesseract...

[image]

You may get on better enlarging them and sharpeneing them with ImageMagick like this:

```
convert email.gif -resize 600x -unsharp 0x8 -threshold 95% x.png     # Enlarge and sharpen
tesseract x.png text                                                 # OCR
```

[image]

**Result**

```
tour@chworldtraveI.com
```

If your CSV file looks like your example, and is called `file.csv`
    http://d1hnc0v5nyu4l2.cloudfront.net/kh/communications/original/1417577580/C2AFA720-7A9C-11E4-9201-22000AA51306?1417577580
    http://d306v9rz034cgu.cloudfront.net/kh/communications/original/1367212416/55BE4627-B463-4523-8332-4046835D3D79?1367212416

you might write

```
#!/bin/bash
while read f; do
   convert "$f" -resize 600x -unsharp 0x8 -threshold 95% image.png
   tesseract image.png text
   grep "[a-z0-9]" text.txt >> results.txt
done < file.csv
```

And your file `results.txt` will have

```
sale@myeIitetour.net
cambodia]et@onIine.com.kh
```

If you do indeed plan to use `ImageMagick` or `tesseract` on OSX, please consider installing it with `homebrew`. It will make your life easier. Ask if you don't know how.

**Original Answer**

Well, it may be a start to use `tesseract`. Basically, you pass it the name of an input image file (`email.png` in my example) and the base of an output text file, like this:

```
tesseract email.png text -psm 7
```

Then you will get some text in file `text.txt` like this

```
lmAV@chwL7v\d1vave\z:um
```

You can try all sorts of different parameters and strategies for cleaning up your input file, probably using ImageMagick.

As you don't say what OS you use, or what your CSV file looks like, it is hard to help any further at the moment.

Comment: HOW-TO In Windows environments ?